# Conditional matrix operation in python

Tags: python, function, matrix, conditional-statements

x is a list of n values from 0 to 1 with which is created with linepace. y=x^3. How can I create a conditional function that keeps the value at 0.01 for whenever x<0.5. n can vary. Is there a way of doing this without having to loop through all values directly through a matrix operation?

```
import numpy as np
n=100
x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
y = np.power(x,3) 
# for all values where x<0.5: y=0.01
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quite easily using:

```
y[x<0.5] = 0.01
```

Sample Output:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: n=10

In [3]: x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)

In [4]: y = np.power(x,3)

In [5]: x
Out[5]:
array([ 0.        ,  0.11111111,  0.22222222,  0.33333333,  0.44444444,
        0.55555556,  0.66666667,  0.77777778,  0.88888889,  1.        ])

In [6]: y
Out[6]:
array([ 0.        ,  0.00137174,  0.01097394,  0.03703704,  0.0877915 ,
        0.17146776,  0.2962963 ,  0.47050754,  0.70233196,  1.        ])

In [7]: y[x<0.5] = 0.01

In [8]: y
Out[8]:
array([ 0.01      ,  0.01      ,  0.01      ,  0.01      ,  0.01      ,
        0.17146776,  0.2962963 ,  0.47050754,  0.70233196,  1.        ])
```